# iOS dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib

Tags: ios, libc++

The iOS application i'm creating uses ZXing, Couchbase and Couchcocoa. Originally I only needed libc++.dylib and I can run the program using the Simulator.

When I tried running on the device, it builds successfully but then crashes and I get the log:

```
    dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/E6AD6AC4-4081-4608-86FB-306D86DCFD35/qrcard.app/qrcard
  Reason: image not found
```

I then added libc++.1.dylib in the link binary libraries. And I still get the same logs.

Comment: I had the same issue. The reason I found out is that code is incompatible with OS version. Execute your code on latest OS 6.1 or so.

Comment: Confirmed...This is OS issue. Check the library version and device OS version.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just renaming your `main.m` to `main.mm`? That will tell Xcode to link against C++ dependences itself. I'm wondering if there are load path flags you have to give the build if you try to explicitly name C++ libraries (which isn't even all that well defined in Xcode anymore since Apple now provides multiple versions of at least some of the C++ libraries.)

It may not be the only way, just the only one I've used. But I've never gotten an error with this method.